# NotImplementedError: Creating a deepcopy of a CVXPY expression is not supported. Use .copy() instead

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

```
ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S, weight_bounds=(None, None))
ef.add_constraint(lambda w: w[0] >= 0.2)
ef.add_constraint(lambda w: w[2] == 0.15)
ef.add_constraint(lambda w: w[3] + w[4] <= 0.10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plotting.plot_efficient_frontier(ef, ax=ax, show_assets=True)
plt.show()
```

Mu is expected return in array form. S is covariance matrix. I got this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide the entire traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're facing this problem while using the PyPortfolioOpt library?

The line that produces the error is

```
plotting.plot_efficient_frontier(ef, ax=ax, show_assets=True)
```

I've had the same error when running this code on python 3.7. The fix was to switch to python 3.10. Then the error dissapears and the plot shows fine.